# execute python module from php exec

Tags: php, xampp

I want to run a python module test.py, from a php file, trial.php. I'm using XAMPP and Windows. My php code is:

```
<?php
exec('"C:\\Python27\python.exe test.py"',$op);
?>
```

But it's not running.
I'm guessing this is a permissions issue.
How do I get it to work?

Comment: did you check the various logfiles?

Comment: I think you've got a problem with the quotes... try: `exec('C:\\Python27\python.exe test.py',$op);`